# How do I remove a site that hasn't been activated?

Tags: cloudflare

I have a domain that needs to be removed. I set it up but never changed the settings at the registrar. The documentation says to use the Overview app, but I do not seem to have access. How do I do remove the site from my dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Overview page in the far bottom right there is a "Remove from Cloudflare" link. I believe this is here even when you have not verified your site.

[image: Link to Remove from Cloudflare]